# Regex replace Big file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So I have a big file of 3000 lines. I need to find the first occurence of  $SETGLOBAL and I need to change the word after the first occurence of this word. To do this I use the following regex expression

```
with open("textfile.txt","r") as F:
      FF=F.read()
FF=re.sub("\$SETGLOBAL\s(.*)", FF ,"CCCC",1)
F2 = open("textfile.txt","w").write(FF)
```

The problem is that in order to change the text in my huge file I also need regex to capture everything before and after this occurrence. So I can write the new text file with the changed word in it.

How would I do this?

My problem is that I need the entire file in my variable FF. so I can write it to a new file.

Imagine I have for example the following file :

```
123456
$SETGLOBAL AAAA
BBBBBB
$SETGLOBAL TTTT
```

What I need is a new file as following

```
123456
$SETGLOBAL CCCC
BBBBBB
$SETGLOBAL TTTT
```

But my solution overwrites everything and I am left with only

```
$SETGLOBAL CCCC
```

in my new file

Comment: Do you mean you just need `FF=re.sub(r"\$SETGLOBAL\b", text ,aa, 1)`? Replace something only once?

Comment: There is really no point consuming all the text after a word unless you are doing that in Notepad++ that has its own quirks. Please clarify what you mean by *the problem is that then the group that I need changes if the text before the first occurence changes so my code wouldn't work anymore.* Some example would help.

Comment: yes I only need to change it once, so the 1 in the end does exactly that. I edit my question to include it. My problem is the following : I need a new file with all of the text of the previous file and the changed word. When I do it with re.sub the entire file gets overwritten and all that is left is the substituted text.

Comment: I edited the question to show it is not a duplicate, and to answer your question.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r"(\$SETGLOBAL\s+)\w+", r"\1{}".format(text), aa, 1)`

Comment: That also deletes everything else in the file and I am left with : $SETGLOBAL $SETGLOBAL CCCC

Comment: See https://ideone.com/bLk2dH, you are not using what I suggest.

Comment: My bad, what you are saying works perfectly! thank you so much. Where can I read a bit more about your solution to understand how it works?

Comment: I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the left-hand context in a capturing group and just match any word to later replace with a backreference to the group value and another word:

```
import re
aa='''123456
$SETGLOBAL AAAA
BBBBBB
$SETGLOBAL TTTT'''
text="CCCC"
print(re.sub(r"(\$SETGLOBAL\s+)\w+", r"\1{}".format(text), aa, 1))
# or
# print(re.sub(r"(\$SETGLOBAL\s+)\S+", r"\1{}".format(text), aa, 1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bLk2dH)

Here,

- `(\$SETGLOBAL\s+)\w+` - matches and captures `$SETGLOBAL` and any 1+ whitespace chars into Group 1 (later referenced with `\1` from the replacement pattern), and just matches 1 or more word chars with `\w+` (`\w` matches any letters, digits or `_` chars (and some more Unicode chars if you use it in Python 3, or when using `re.U` flag in Python 2.x). **NOTE:** `\S+` will match 1 or more any non-whitespace chars.
- `\1` - is the backreference to the value stored in Group 1 buffer

The `1` argument is the *limit* argument, it tells `re.sub` to only replace once, the first match.